# Launch RDP session in mobaXterm via CLI

Tags: mobaxterm

Does anyone know of a way to launch an ad-hoc (not bookmarked) session in mobaXterm via CLI?  Ideally I can make moba my default handler for .rdp files, but when I try to associate .rdp files with moba, it just tries to execute all of the parameters in the file on the CLI, but fails to launch a session.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030717/start-a-session-in-mobaxterm-from-batch-script for a possible answer, e.g., `MobaXterm_Personal_20.6.exe -newtab "ssh -l username 192.168.1.99"`

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, That works for SSH, but I'm looking to start an RDP session.